# JSON Format Output -Angular

Tags: json, angular

I realised the format of your json output can cause an error in your application. How can i get a format of this sought in my code below? I can't really see where my error is coming from. Although, i am able to see my data. I want the objects to be in the topics but with my response the objects are in another array ( 0:[]) which is in the topics. How can get the objects under topic instead.

**JSON Format - Preferred**

```
lesson: "Angular 2 JSON"
topics:[]

    routing,
    navigation
```

**My JSON response**

```
 lesson: "Angular 2 JSON"
        topics:[]
         0:[]

            routing,
            navigation
```

**response from backend**

```
"tutorial": "Angular 2 Lessons",
  "topics": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "routing",

    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "params",

    }
  ],
  "number of  lessons": 2
}

//how i submit in backend test 

    "tutorials" : "Angular 2 lessons",
    "topics" : {
        "1" : {
             "id": 3,
          "name": "routing",
```

**checkbox html**

```
<input  #{{Topics[key].id}} type="checkbox" (change)="checkbox(Topics[key])">
```

**ts**

```
 checkbox(Topics){
            Topics.selected = (Topics.selected) ? false : true;
            this.topicSelected = Topics;

        }

//and this is how i submit to the  array

//array 

 tutorials =   { 
                lessons : "",

                topics : [{
                names: "",


         }]

            }


submitJSON(){
   //topicSelected are a list of the topics selected.

   this.tutorials.topics['0'] = this.topicSelected;

}
```

Comment: Could you post the actual response in JSON format and the JSON format you wish to have?

Comment: @AJT_82 that is what i have in the question, please

Comment: That is not JSON format... JSON format looks something like this: `{"lesson":"Angular...."}` :)

Comment: @AJT_82, question updated. when i do a test on my backend, this is the kind of JSON response i get

Comment: Okay great! Much clearer now :) But now the question, how do you want it to look like instead?

Comment: @AJT_82, just like how the backend submits it and you can see in the updated question how i submit  the data during my backend test. I don't think the frontend submission conforms

Comment: I thought you wanted to manipulate the data somehow and change the build of the data, but apparently not? You mean you *want* to send some data in that format to the backend?

Comment: Exactly!. if you look the labeled code (my code), that is now i send to the backend, well, i see the parameters are all submitted but it fails to go to the database

Comment: Now I understand! but where does this data come from which you want to send to backend, is it some form data or what? Just thinking of if it's e.g a form, then why not format the form to such that the data will be in correct format :)

Comment: @AJT_82  the data i am submitting is from `this.topicSelected`; i get the data from the checkbox that i select and place all selected topics into the array

Comment: Okay, now I think I have gotten all pieces together :D If you'll just add the html part of those checkboxes, so that I can see the code and then maybe help you :)

Comment: @AJT_82 question updated with ts of the html part as well

Comment: Could you just try and create a plunker instead, since okay good, now we can see the html part. But now... how does `Topics` look like? We need to know these kind of things to be able to reproduce the issue. The code presented should be: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your Json is not valid, try to use this format (you can test your Json format in an online website for eg: jsonlint) :

```
tutorials = {
"lessons": "",

"topics": [{
    "names": ""
}]
}
```